# Python image recognition going around objects to create quadrilateral polygons

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

I have an image and I want the image recognition to pick up quadrilaterals/trapezoid-like polygons from the image. What I want the bounding box to do is to create boxes around areas.

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rN7Z.png)

[Contours drawn on image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGhd0.png)

[Problem area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqhbJ.png)

[What I want it to look like at the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ltu76.png)

From the image, it goes around the specific objects in the picture but I want it to skip those and just create boxes instead. Around the bottom of the image, it is doing what I want it to do, create boxes around the 'blocks' in the image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread("map3.png")

imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 110, 255, 
                            cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for contour in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    if area > 500:
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, .002*cv2.arcLength(contour, True), True)
        if len(approx) >= 4:
            cv2.drawContours(img, [approx], -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)


cv2.imshow("IMAGE", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Please show your source image, and also indicate where you want polygons creted, perhaps by a separate image with examples drawn onto it.

Comment: Edited with original image uploaded and a rough sketch of what I want it to look like. I want to create a bounding box for each 'block' in the image.